# Uniscan: loadable library and perl binaries are mismatched

Tags: c, linux, perl

Uniscan is a tool for scanning websites which comes in kali linux and other pen tests distros. I used to use it weekly to test my applications but after some updates of my linux tools it is now giving the following error when I run it:

> xs/Moose.c: loadable library and perl binaries are mismatched (got handshake key 0xdb00080, needed 0xdb80080)

My current perl version is `5.24.0`. I read somewhere that this problem can be bypassed if I downgrade perl version but I didn't found to which version it should be downgraded, I also tried all versions that are available at my package manager cache, none worked, it actually changed the `.c` file that got the handshake mismatch. I also tried updating Uniscan to the most recent version (6.3.1), also nothing.

Anyway, does anyone know how to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like you are using a module with one build of Perl that was installed with a different build of Perl. The `PERL5LIB` env var probably points to somewhere inapproporiate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This error message is coming from the perl interpreter's `Perl_xs_handshake` function. From a comment:

> implement the various XS_*_BOOTCHECK macros, which are added to .c
>      files by ExtUtils::ParseXS, to check that the perl the module was built
>      with is binary compatible with the running perl.

In short, this means that the `Moose` perl module is built against an incompatible version of the perl interpreter (i.e. downgrading `perl` is a possible option, but this has its own set of issues).

`Moose` is an object oriented extension framework for perl. It's common enough that some distros pre-build it and include it in the distro as a separate package (e.g. Under fedora, there is a `perl-Moose` fedora package).

But, `Moose` is also available as a `CPAN` package.

So, if your distro (kali) was set up correctly, things should take care of themselves (which they didn't). That is, if kali upgraded `perl`, they should have rebuilt the various perl module packages (`Moose` being one of them).

Or ... `Moose` was *never* installed from the distro, but was installed from `CPAN` (e.g. as part of something else).

Another way to go is to invoke [`cpan`](https://metacpan.org/pod/cpan) and download, rebuild, and install the `Moose` package from there.

One thing to look for is to find the place where the current `Moose` is installed (e.g. `/usr/lib64/...` or `/usr/local/lib64/...`, etc.) by doing `perldoc -lm Moose`. This may help with configuring `cpan` as to install directories.

---

**UPDATE:**

> I couldn't find out how to use cpan to rebuild Moose alone, I tried "cpan Moose" (with -c, -m, also tried to download and install using -g, none worked) so I ran a cpan -u to update all installed modules. After that the problem persists.

There are two types of packages: *distro* packages (e.g. kali packages) and `CPAN` packages. If a given perl module has been installed from the *distro*, it is unlikely that `cpan` will try to update it. What we'll need to do is to get `cpan` to *install* it (from `CPAN`).

When I use `cpan`, I usually do `/full_path_to/perl -MCPAN -e shell`. The reason I use a full path is that I have multiple different perl versions installed. For background as to why I have these [and *had* to have them], see my answer https://serverfault.com/questions/741186/cpan-is-using-old-perl-version-to-install-modules/741216#741216

After that, at the prompt, I usually do something like `install Moose`. It will look for package dependencies and I usually say yes to all.

`cpan` allows a few different install "modes". Notably, installing system-wide (i.e. you are a `sudo` user) or installing to a subdirectory under your $HOME directory. This allows a non-root user to install a CPAN module even if the local sysadmin won't allow the install to `/usr/lib64/...`

Look in `$HOME/.cpan` Of particular interest is `$HOME/.cpan/CPAN/MyConfig.pm`. In that text file, look for the install related information: `'make_install_make_command' => q[sudo /usr/bin/make]`. It may or may not have the `sudo` on it. There are a few other similar options in there (`mbuild_install_build_command`). If they don't have `sudo` on them, you *can* hand edit the file.

We'll get back to this in a bit. But, the first thing to do is to run `uniscan` under `strace`. No matter how things are configured, versioned, etc. this will record what is going on. Here's a script with the options I'd recommend for `strace`:

```
strace -ttt -i -f -ff -etrace=all -o /anyplace/log/whatever.spysys \
-eread=0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 -ewrite=0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 \
-eread=11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21 \
-ewrite=11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21 \
-eread=22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32 \
-ewrite=22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32 \
-eread=33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43 \
-ewrite=33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43 \
-eread=44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54 \
-ewrite=44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54 \
-eread=55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65 \
-ewrite=55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65 \
-eread=66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76 \
-ewrite=66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76 \
-eread=77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87 \
-ewrite=77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87 \
-eread=88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98 \
-ewrite=88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98 -eread=99 -ewrite=99 -x \
/usr/bin/whatever
```

Replace the `/anyplace/...` with something suitable for your system. Replace `/usr/bin/whatever` with the `uniscan` command that is failing. If you normally run `uniscan` as root, you can prefix `strace` with `sudo`

Note that these options to `strace` generate a *lot* of output but they don't leave anything of value out. Eventually, the `uniscan` command will abort [as you've already been experiencing], but, now, the `strace` output will have the reason why.

Specifically, by sifting through the log output, you can find the exact full path of the failing `Moose.so`. That is, `perl` will open a Moose related file (successfully) and soon thereafter output the failure message to stderr. The moose file might be in `/usr/lib64/...` or it might be in some totally strange place like `/usr/local/lib64/...` or, even stranger, `/usr/lib64/uniscan/lib/Moose/...`. But, this now tells us *where* we want to rebuild and install moose to.

**Note:** As you may have noticed, my original answer got edited [pedantically] for grammar, but, materially to replace my recommendation for using `find` [which I didn't approve of].

Anyway, to match up the `cpan` and `strace` stuff. When you used `cpan`, it may have run in the "install to `$HOME/...`" mode, which, IIRC is the default. So, if that were the case (i.e. check `MyConfig.pm`), you may find the updated packages under your home directory rather than the desired system-wide directories. So, to help verify this, do `find $HOME -name '*Moose*'` and see what comes up.

So, based on the `strace` filenames, the timestamps on the files *should* match up with the time that you did your `cpan` commands. But, I'm betting they won't.

Under `$HOME/.cpan` there is a subdirectory `$HOME/.cpan/build`. This is where the `cpan` command downloads and stores the package files. It also builds the packages there. If your invocation of `cpan` touched on Moose, there should be some `*Moose*` files and directories there.

Whenever I've had a "bad" package, IIRC, I just removed it from `$HOME/.cpan/build` (and some of the dependent packages) and then did `install` again. Things get redownloaded, rebuilt, and reinstalled.

From the `strace` we now *know* which perl interpreter was used (probably `/usr/bin/perl`), where it got the moose file from. The moose file should be under one of the `@INC` directories. If so, fine. If not, this means that the "wrapper" script for `uniscan` is setting up a non-standard path for Moose, which is the reason to do the strace: to confirm this or not.

Then, fix the `MyConfig.pm` if needed. If it was missing `sudo`, that may be all you need. Then, just do `install Moose`.

You could remove `$HOME/.cpan/build` first if you wanted.

Comment: Hello. I couldn't find out how to use cpan to rebuild Moose alone, I tried "cpan Moose" (with -c, -m, also tried to download and install using -g, none worked) so I ran a `cpan -u` to update all installed modules. After that the problem persists. What else can I try? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A simple `cpan -r` fixed the problem for me. It took a few dozen minutes to run.

This is already hinted at in Craig Estey's [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38155901/118220), but perhaps some readers would like to give it a shot, and read more about the how & why while waiting for it to complete.